# Bootsrap expand on a link, plus link to another page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a page that lists out a whole bunch of categories and their associated items.  What I'd like to do is have this page list the categories, and if you click on one, it expands to show the items in that category.  I'm using bootstrap's built in expand/collapse functionality to make this happen.

This is fine, unless the js doesn't load (which might be the case if there's a js error, you're on a slow mobile connection and the js hasn't downloaded yet, etc). To account for these cases, I want my categories to link to a stand alone category page.

The problem is that when you click on the category, it expands the list of items, but then takes you to the category page instead of keeping you where you are at.

Any idea how I can resolve this?  I know I can use return false, but I really don't want to start making modifications to the bootstrap.js file.

Thanks!

```
<a class="toggle_div" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".category_56"  href="link.html">
  Category 56
</a>
<div class=" category_56 in">
  Here is the info to expand and collapse
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This attribute:

```
href="link.html"
```

is your problem.

If you need to test if the related div is fully loaded you may do this:

```
$($(this).data('target')).length == 1
```

where this is your toggle_div anchor.

So a possible solution could be:

```js
$('.toggle_div').on('click', function(e) {
  
  if ($($(this).data('target')).length == 1) {
    //
    // if the related div is loaded you can prevent default action
    //
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    // goto next page
  }

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a class="toggle_div" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".category_56"  href="link.html">
    Category 56
</a>
<div class=" category_56 in">
    Here is the info to expand and collapse
</div>
```